# Background url from href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get url from href and paste it in background image. 
The problem is that it is applying to just first div not on all div. Is this possible without giving unique classes?

**HTML**

```
<div id="main-bg"> text 
<div id="inner-content"> <a href="smile0.png"></a> </div> 

</div>

<div id="main-bg"> text 
<div id="inner-content"> <a href="smile1.png"></a> </div> 

</div>


<div id="main-bg"> text 
<div id="inner-content"> <a href="smile2.png"></a> </div> 

</div>


<div id="main-bg"> text 
<div id="inner-content"> <a href="smile3.png"></a> </div> 

</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#main-bg').css(
'background-image', 'url(' + $('#inner-content a').attr('href') + ')'
);
```

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/pr07zymf/

Comment: An `id` **MUST** be unique to each element. Use classes instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `id` **MUST** be unique to each element! Using it multiple times may work at times in CSS, though, JavaScript isn't so forgiving. The reason only the first `<div>` is styled is because JavaScript ignores all other elements with the same id.

You can use classes instead as shown in the example below!

**Example Code:**

```js
/* Iterate over every element having the given class. */
$('.main-bg').each(function (index, element) {
  /* Cache a jQuery instance of the element. */
  var el = $(element);
  
  /* Get the 'href' and assign it as the 'background-image' for each element. */
  el.css('background-image', 'url(' + el.find('.inner-content a').attr('href') + ')');
});
```

```css
.main-bg {color: #fff}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-bg"> text
  <div class="inner-content">
    <a href="//cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/03/01/00/21/bridge-19513_960_720.jpg"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main-bg"> text
  <div class="inner-content">
    <a href="//cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/09/07/22/17/forest-438432_960_720.jpg"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main-bg"> text
  <div class="inner-content">
    <a href="//cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/09/05/04/27/milky-way-923738_960_720.jpg"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main-bg"> text
  <div class="inner-content">
    <a href="//cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/31/06/50/forest-868715_960_720.jpg"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forget to use classes instead of ID. But after replacing it's showing same image for all divs. https://jsfiddle.net/pr07zymf/14/

Comment: Sorry @YanHayie, Ithat was typo that I've fixed now 

Comment: I'm glad I could be of assistance @YanHayie!

Answer (score 1):

When you are using HTML, please remember, the ID should always be **UNIQUE**.
You cannot make them the same name like "main-bg".

Solutions:

1, change their id's name to `<div id ="main-bg1">`, `<div id ="main-bg2">`, `<div id ="main-bg3">`, and `<div id ="main-bg4">`

2, use **CLASS** like

```
<div class="main-bg"> text 
<div class="inner-content"> <a href="smile3.png"></a> </div>
```

And remember, every time when you do

```
$('#ID')
```

or

```
document.getElementById(ID)
```

It will always choose the **FIRST** element which has this ID.